# expect error in bash expression

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I have the following expect command that i use in my bash script in order to set passwordless ssh connection.

```
VAR=$(expect -c '
     spawn ssh-copy-id -i '"$SSH_KEY_PATH_PUB $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP "'   
     expect "*?assword:*"
     send "'"$REMOTE_HOST_PASSWD"'\r";
     expect { 
     "Permission denied, please try again." {
        exit '"$WRONG_PASSWORD"' 
     }
 }
 ')
```

I am expecting password string as "*?assword:*" in order to send password.But whatever i write for the expect block it works.if i write

```
expect "xxxx"
expect "yyyy"
```

it also works, so i think it does not enter that block?.What is the solution

Answer (score 0):

it could be that before a match is made, it reaches the end of the steam or a timeout occurs. Even if no match is found, expect will return and execution will continue, sending the password.

From the expect manual, under `COMMAND`, we have a section that explains the `expect` command:

```
waits until one of the patterns matches the output of a spawned process, a
specified time period has passed, or an end-of-file is seen.
```

To fix this, you should place the send code in expect's body:

```
VAR=$(expect -c '
     spawn ssh-copy-id -i '"$SSH_KEY_PATH_PUB $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP "'   
     expect "*?assword:*" {
       send "'"$REMOTE_HOST_PASSWD"'\r"
     }
     expect { 
     "Permission denied, please try again." {
        exit '"$WRONG_PASSWORD"' 
     }
 }
 ')
```

Hope this helps =)